# Hibernate 2 with MSSQL for ORDER BY

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have been working with Oracle and Postgre and recently switched to MS SQL 2012. 
I use hibernate in my application and wherever I have used the Order by Criteria:

```
(criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("applicationId")));
```

It causes an error saying:

> aggregate functions dont work.

Once I comment that line out my program works and data can be retrieved.

I'm using Hibernate 3.

Is there any way to order it through hibernate without this error?

edit..

This is one error I get,

> Column "SKY.tcrent.RENTNO" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

**Edit 2..**

MY query

```
  Query tcSchaduleQ = getSession().createQuery("SELECT SUM(tcs.dueAmount) FROM TrialCalculationSchedule tcs WHERE tcs.facilityId=:facilityId AND tcs.rentalNumber>:rentalNumber AND tcs.dueDate>:dueDate AND dueTypeId IN(:dueTypeId) ORDER BY tcs.rentalNumber ").setInteger("rentalNumber", facility.getPeriod() - noOfprePayments).setInteger("facilityId",facility.getFacilityId()).setDate("dueDate", date).setParameterList("dueTypeId", plist);

  Number tcsAmt = (Number) tcSchaduleQ.uniqueResult();
```

and this is what hibernate generates in HQL

```
SELECT
    SUM(tcs.dueAmount) 
FROM
    TrialCalculationSchedule tcs 
WHERE
    tcs.facilityId=:facilityId 
    AND tcs.rentalNumber>:rentalNumber 
    AND tcs.dueDate>:dueDate 
    AND dueTypeId IN(
        :dueTypeId
    ) 
ORDER BY
    tcs.rentalNumber
```

and this is the SQL

```
select
        SUM(trialcalcu0_.DUEAMT) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        SKYBANKSLFHP.tcrent trialcalcu0_ 
    where
        trialcalcu0_.FACID=? 
        and trialcalcu0_.RENTNO>? 
        and trialcalcu0_.DUEDATE>? 
        and (
            trialcalcu0_.DUETYPEID in (
                ? , ?
            )
        ) 
    order by
        trialcalcu0_.RENTNO
```

Comment: Can you post more source code? ORDER BY isn't an aggregate function by itself (SUM, COUNT etc. are).

Comment: See https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2436442

Comment: voting down, because what you are asking (about criteria API) does not match your code (HQL) also claiming two different error messages are happening.

Answer (score 0):

Look Like you mix aggregate and non-aggregate expressions .If you are using any aggregate function like `AVG()` in `Select` query with some other non-aggregate then you must use `Group By` ..

Try something like this

```
createQuery("SELECT SUM(tcs.dueAmount) As DueAmount  ...
```

If you are using Criteria then it should be like this

```
  Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(Insurance.class);
  ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
  proList.add(Projections.sum("investementAmount"));
  crit.setProjection(proList);
  List sumResult = crit.list();
```

Comment: I have edited the question please take a look at the last lines

Comment: Where is your query? Please share it also

Comment: Edited again. please check

Comment: In your Criteria query give some name to `SUM(tcs.dueAmount)` dont directly use it also you told you are using criteria but here you used `createQuery` ?

Comment: like, "SUM(tcs.dueAmount) as sum" ?

Comment: Yeah not here, there are other places I Have used criteria

Comment: List cancelList = cancelStatusCriteria.list();
  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("companyId", userConfig.getCompanyId()));
  if ((cancelList!=null)&&(cancelList.size()>0))
   criteria.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("applicationStatusId", cancelStatusCriteria.list())));
  
  //criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("applicationId"));
  criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
  if (to != -1) {
   criteria.setFirstResult(from);
   criteria.setMaxResults(to);
  }
  Collection<Application> collection=criteria.list();

Comment: @Sachi Pj you share query and now you made changes in `Criteria`   ? Are you Using SQL or Criteria?

Comment: these are two different programs. One in query and one in criteria. Both give errors and both work if I remove the order by.

Comment: Ok i bit confuse somewhere you have added SQL code and not the criteria

Comment: Yes I badly need solutions for both these matters. Query or criteria both gives me errors

Comment: Both giving exception is mean you are doing something wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83861/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-sachi-pj).